# Download image though .php - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am downloading a .jpg image through a .PHP file. It works perfect. I am testing with a link on a blank .HTML page.

But now i want to integrate the link on an Wordpress page, after click it seems that it can't connect to the .php file.

Anyone knows how to connect the a href URL to the .php file?

HTML

```
<a href="download-image.php">Download</a>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$file = 'images/test.jpg';

header("Expires: 0");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$basename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);

header("Content-type: application/".$ext);
// tell file size
header('Content-length: '.filesize($file));
// set file name
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$basename\"");
readfile($file);

exit;
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: where have you uploaded 'download-image.php' file?

Comment: in the theme folder, but i can place it somewhere else if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the right path.

I assume your file is located in the root folder. So try adding the '/':

```
<a href="/download-image.php">Download</a>
```

From the theme folder:

```
<a href="/wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/download-image.php">Download</a>
```

Comment: That is not working when placing the a tag in a Wordpress template. Wordpress redirects to the "page not found" page.

Comment: What is the absolute path of your `download-image.php`?

Comment: /webspace/httpdocs/MYSITE/wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/download-image.php

Comment: So it should be `/wp-content/themes/MYTHEME/download-image.php`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you